# Convert raster cells to vector (polygon) grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid, raster-conversion

I would like to convert a raster (representing a study area) to a polygon layer with features representing individual raster cells.

The raster layer contains roughly 30 million cells @150x150m.

I have tried using the Create Fishnet tool, but I want the cells to match the study boundary, not the study area boundaries EXTENT (i.e. many more unnecessary grid cells), and selecting the grid cells from the fishnet that intersect with the boundary area does not work (freezes) because of the large number of grid cells (~30 million).

Could anyone recommend a procedure for converting the raster to vector grid cells?

Comment: Polygon to raster, raster to points, points to raster using pointID, raster to polygon

Comment: Follow @FelixIP idea but make sure you are writing to a file geodatabase and not a shapefile as you will likely exceed the specifications of a shapefile.